# Kendo UI - Datagrid, how to add additional params to request?

Tags: post, datagrid, kendo-ui

I have editable datagrid. I would like to change read transport to POST and add some additional data to json request (for example access_token).

Example below produce GET request instead of the POST and without additional data.

Question is: How can i do that?

```
dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
              transport: {
                  read:  {
                      type: "POST",
                      url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "/Products",
                      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                      dataType: "jsonp",
                      data: { "my_param": 1}
                  },
                  update: {
                      type: "PUT",
                      url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "/Products/Update",
                      dataType: "jsonp",
                      data: { "my_param": 1}
                  },
                  destroy: {
                      type: "DELETE",
                      url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "/Products/Destroy",
                      dataType: "jsonp",
                      data: { "my_param": 1}
                  },
                  create: {
                      url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "/Products/Create",
                      dataType: "json",
                      type: "PUT",
                      data: { "my_param": 1}
                  },
                  parameterMap: function(options, operation) {
                          console.log(options);
                          console.log(operation);
                          return {data: kendo.stringify(options.models)};
                  }

              },
```

Answer (score 1):

Several options:

Option 1. Use [`transport.read.data`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/framework/datasource#configuration-transport-read-data)

```
read:  {
    type: "POST",
    url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "/Products",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    data: { "my_param": 1, access_token : "my_token" }  // send parameter "access_token" with value "my_token" with the `read` request
}
```

Option 2. Add them into [`transport.paremeterMap`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/framework/datasource#configuration-transport-parameterMap) function

```
parameterMap: function(options, operation) {
    console.log(options);
    console.log(operation);
    if (operation.type === "read") {
        // send parameter "access_token" with value "my_token" with the `read` request
        return {
            data: kendo.stringify(options.models),
            access_token: "my_token"
        };
    } else
        return {data: kendo.stringify(options.models)};
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but both methods above process request like :
Request Method:OPTIONS and not POST or GET. 

Without given params.

Comment: If you check the documentation [here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/framework/datasource#configuration-transport-read-type), it says "The type option is ignored if dataType is set to "jsonp". JSONP always uses GET requests."