# Kendo ui grid - get data send on READ on my php

Tags: php, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24161502/1216501) answer reagarding sending extra params on performing a READ operation, but how do i access that var on the on my php?

This is my code on client-side:

```
          dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
          transport: {
              read: 
              {
                url:"basedados.php",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                data: { "my_param": 1, access_token : "my_token" },  // send parameter "access_token" with value "my_token" with the `read` request
              },
```

but now on my .php file, how do i access it?:

```
  else
  {
    $verb = $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"];

    if ($verb == "POST") 
    {
        header("Content-type: application/json");

        if($_POST['access_token']) // do i say it like this?
        {

            $formData = $_POST["access_token"];
            echo $formData;

        }
```

**EDIT:** Thanks for answering Rick s, but let show you more of my code:

```
parameterMap: function(options, operation) 
              {
                if (operation == "read" && options.models) 
                {     
                   return {models: kendo.stringify(options.models)};
                 };
                if (operation == "create" && options.models) 
                {
                   options.models[0].idPai = currentId;
                  $('#gridBaseDados').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.read();

                  return {models: kendo.stringify(options.models)};
                };

                  if (operation !== "read" && options.models) 
                  {
                      return {models: kendo.stringify(options.models)};
                  }
              }
```

and on my server side, i(usually) HAD this:

```
else
{
    $verb = $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"];


    if ($verb == "GET") 
    {
        header("Content-type: application/json");

        $arr = array();
        $statement = $pdo->query("SELECT a.idDocumento, a.idPai, a.tipo,a.nome,a.dataCriacao,
                a.dataModificacao,b.nome as NomeUtilizadorCriador,
                c.nome as NomeUtilizadorUpdate
                FROM Documento a left outer join Utilizador b on a.idUtilizadorCriador=b.idUtilizadores  
                                  left outer join Utilizador c on a.idUtilizadorUpdate=c.idUtilizadores");

        $statement->execute();
        $result = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        echo json_encode(array("data" => $result, "user" => $_SESSION["user"]));
    }
```

and this works, but i need that extra param, because i need to compare it to my "idPai".

Thanks again.

Comment: One option would be to do it this way: `url:"basedados.php?access_token=my_token"`

Comment: you mean on my put that on my READ url and then on the server side, i say it like this: $verb = $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"];
 

  if ($verb == $_GET["access_token"]) 
  {

Comment: This looks like a php question on "how do I read data sent via a POST".  Try one of these http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+read+post+data

Comment: It kinda is, but it is not also...because i´m using Kendo ui and i already changed that READ to post and i cannot get my extra param on the server side...

Comment: Right now, you are saying you don't know how to read the data that you are sending via a POST.  I don't know PHP, so I can't help with that.  

The method you linked to for adding parameters to a POST works.  I can read that data in on my web api service - but I'm using C#.

You need to look at what is getting sent from your webpage using your browser's dev tools and make sure the POST data actually contains that extra parameter.  If it doesn't, then you've got a kendo question.  If the data is there, you've got a PHP question.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to POST here.  Use the [parameterMap](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource) option to send in your data.

```
dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
      transport: {
          read: 
          {
            url:"basedados.php",
            dataType: "json",
          }, 
          parameterMap: function(options, operation) {
             return {
                access_token : "my_token"
             }
          }
      },
      schema: {
        data: "data"
      }
```

**php**

```
$formData = $_GET["access_token"];
echo $formData;
```